# Две параллельные таблички в С++

Tags: c++, консоль

Суть проблемы такова, требуется нарисовать правила игры (в консоле) в левой стороне, а справа нарисовать поле игры

Comment: Суть проблемы ясна. А в чём ваш вопрос состоит?

Answer (score 1):

Найдите себе любимые оконные библиотеки для консоли. Под Unix, например, можно использовать ncurses. Раньше под DOS был turbo vision от borland. Под нынешние windows - никогда не интересовался, не могу советовать.